# Running multiple motors simultaneously

Tags: arduino-mega, motor

I have this code for a DC motor (using [this](https://github.com/OliviliK/Arduino-Robot/blob/master/libraries/Vnh2sp30/Vnh2sp30.h) library)

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Vnh2sp30.h>

//              ENA A   B   PWM   CS    inv
Vnh2sp30  mtrL( A0, 7,  8,  5,    A2,   0);             

void setup() {                          
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0)   {
    String first  = Serial.readStringUntil(',');
    Serial.read(); 
    String second = Serial.readStringUntil(','); 
    Serial.read();
    String third = Serial.readStringUntil(','); 
    Serial.read();
    String echo = Serial.readString();
    Serial.println(echo);
       if(first == "start"){
                Serial.println("Starting DC motor");
                int duration = atoi(second.c_str());
                int power = atoi(third.c_str());
                int starttime = millis();
                int endtime = starttime;
                while ((endtime - starttime) <= duration) // mS
                {
                  endtime = millis();
                  mtrL.run(1023);
                }
                mtrL.stop();
                Serial.println("DONE");
       }
   }
}
```

Then I have this code to drive multiple stepper motors (using [this](https://github.com/laurb9/StepperDriver/blob/master/src/BasicStepperDriver.h) library):

```cpp
#include "BasicStepperDriver.h"

int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data
String readString = "";

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    motors.begin();
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String first  = Serial.readStringUntil(','); // start
    Serial.read(); 
    String second = Serial.readStringUntil(','); // motor number
    Serial.read();
    String third = Serial.readStringUntil(','); // motor steps
    Serial.read();
    String fourth = Serial.readStringUntil(','); // duration (millisec)
    Serial.read();
    String fifth = Serial.readStringUntil(','); // deg
                if(first == "start") {
                  if(second == "ALL") {
                    Serial.println("Starting stepper motor ALL");
                    int steps = atoi(third.c_str());
                    int duration = atoi(fourth.c_str());
                    int deg = atoi(fifth.c_str());

                    BasicStepperDriver stepper1(steps, DIR, STEP, ENBL);
                    stepper1.enable();
                    stepper1.setMicrostep(MICROSTEPS);
                    stepper1.setRPM(MAX_RPM);

                    BasicStepperDriver stepper2(steps, DIR_2, STEP_2, ENBL_2);
                    stepper2.enable();
                    stepper2.setMicrostep(MICROSTEPS);
                    stepper2.setRPM(MAX_RPM);

                    BasicStepperDriver stepper3(steps, DIR_3, STEP_3, ENBL_3);
                    stepper3.enable();
                    stepper3.setMicrostep(MICROSTEPS);
                    stepper3.setRPM(MAX_RPM);

                    BasicStepperDriver stepper4(steps, DIR_4, STEP_4, ENBL_4);
                    stepper4.enable();
                    stepper4.setMicrostep(MICROSTEPS);
                    stepper4.setRPM(MAX_RPM);

                    int starttime = millis();
                    int endtime = starttime;
                    while ((endtime - starttime) <= duration) // mS
                    {
                      stepper1.rotate(deg);  
                      stepper2.rotate(deg);  
                      stepper3.rotate(deg);
                      stepper4.rotate(deg);
                      endtime = millis();
                    }
                    stepper1.disable();
                    stepper2.disable();
                    stepper3.disable();
                    stepper4.disable();
                    Serial.println("DONE");
                  }
                }
        }
}
```

My goal is to merge this two codes together and still be able to run both the DC motor and one (or all) the stepper motors all together simultaneously. The first code is running on Arduino UNO and the other code runs on Arduino MEGA board and has been tested to work. The goal is to migrate the code from Arduino UNO to the MEGA board. Driving the motor for a specific time will block Arduino from executing the Stepper motors and vice versa with the DC motor. What can be done with these codes to make sure it can run the DC motor and Stepper motors at the same time?

Comment: The line `while ((endtime - starttime) <= duration) // ms`  is what you need to change because it keeps the loop from doing other actions while driving the motor, hence it is referred to as blocking.  The AccelStepper library mentioned by @Visual Micro uses a non-blocking approach but you need to change your approach.  Use some variable to detect the duration and let the code in loop() constantly check it each time though instead of using a while loop. That way each motor can get the attention it needs instead of taking turns.

Answer (score 2):

Use the AccelStepper library along with the Adafruit MotorShield library

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield-v2-for-arduino/install-software

Comment: I don't have a adafruit motor shield just the ones from China

Comment: The library is standard. You don't need the shield. Read the AccelStepper guide and it explains how to use motors and steppers at the same time.

Comment: Would it work for ST Vnh2sp30 driver hardware? I'm not sure if the pinouts match.

Comment: I managed to compile this for Stepper motor connections, problem is with the connection to the VNH2SP30 and if it would be non-blocking.

Comment: I think you van set the pins but the point of Accel is to do non-blocking.